What are the readings of 熱感 and 熱型?
Recently I noticed that in my Shin Meikai dictionary (新明解国語辞典） app, the readings of 熱感 and 熱型 are ねつかん and ねつけい, respectively. This looks quite unusual to me as I would expect that they should go through 促音化 under the usual rules and become ねっかん and ねっけい, respectively. The goo online dictionary shows ねつかん and ねっけい for the two words. For 熱感, the reading of ねっかん can be found in official documents. For 熱型, Wikipedia shows both ねつけい and ねっけい as the reading. When using the Anthy IME, I can only input these words with ねっかん and ねっけい but not the forms before 促音化.
Are there official readings of the two words? What is the reason that 促音化 does not apply (or is only conditionally applied) here? I don't think ねつちゅう would be considered an acceptable reading of 熱中. More generally, what are some other exceptions where the usual rule (specifically, the rules given in this answer) of 促音化 in 漢語 words do not apply? I'm aware that the rule does not apply when an individual word is formed, such as in the case of 熱処理 (処理 is somehow considered a word on its own and hence it doesn't become ねっしょり), but it does not seem to be the case here.

Although Japanese has the 常用漢字表, it doesn't have an "official" Japanese dictionary similar to the Dictionnaire de l'Académie française in French. Usually, a large dictionary, especially 広辞苑, serves as the de facto standard, but its usefulness is limited when it comes to highly technical terms including 熱感 and 熱型. Generally speaking, the rarer the word is, the less likely gemination and other euphonic changes occur, but there is no strict rule.
As for these two terms specifically, I think I hear ねっかん and ねっけい more commonly from healthcare providers. ねつかん sounds unfamiliar, but ねつけい sounds perfectly acceptable to me. (灼熱感 is always read しゃくねつかん.) Medical dictionaries may include these terms along with their readings, but I don't own one, and even professional healthcare providers don't usually refer to them when reading such words.

Thank you. Are you aware of any less technical term (exception) where the gemination should apply according to the "general" rule given in that answer linked above, but does not actually apply?

@WeijunZhou I recalled this recent question.

Thank you, that is very helpful. Let me know (or just edit into the answer) if you have more examples.
